# How can I knock people out?

Tags: dishonored

So far the only way I've found to take people down without killing them is Sleep Darts. None of my skills (that I've noticed) seem to be able to knock people out/put them to sleep. I noticed the "parry" button is also "choke" but when sneaking up on someone and pressing parry I just block, I don't seem to choke them; I'm also unsure whether that's lethal or not.

What are all the ways to knock someone unconscious? There seem to be very few.

Comment: I wish the game had a non-lethal unarmed combat option, so that you can punch somebody's lights out without killing them if they have detected you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sneak up and choke them. It's the RB on Xbox (Holding X after choking will automatically pick up the body for you to hide it). It's non-lethal and will not increase the death count.

*However*, if the unconscious body falls down stairs, off a high platform/balcony/etc., into water, they can die and that will increase kill count. Other enemies can also found the unconscious body and be alerted to your presence, so make sure to hide them after knocking em out. Other than that, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Is there a prompt for the choking action? There's a little image in a circle when I'm close enough for a throat-stab but I haven't seen the same prompt for chocking (unless being able to stab is the same as being able to choke and it only shows one icon)

Comment: @Ben It's been a while since I played but yes, there should be a circle showing you can choke them. Now that I think about it, I had the same problem where I would parry when I wanted to choke. You just have to make sure your directly behind them and not off to the side or anything.

Comment: Perhaps that's it then, I don't always approach from the rear since the stab works at any angle

Comment: Yea that sounds right. Also AFAIK, sleep darts and choking are the only ways to knock someone out.

Comment: @BenBrocka You should see a prompt to press and hold Left Ctrl if you're playing on PC. But it won't pop up unless you are behind them, as stated.

Answer (score 3):

Sneaking up and choking out is the only way other than using sleep darts, but if you're dealing with a guard who has already been alerted (and you're out of sleep darts), you can use Time Bend Tier 2 to stop time, go behind the alerted guard, and choke them out before time returns to normal.